# How do you avoid the style = clear:both when using floating elements?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Usually when I have floating elements inside a container div, I'll have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="float: left;">content</div>
  <div style="float: left;">content</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I find it extremely annoying and ugly to have that `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` on every fluid piece of layout. So I tried to do something like this (using css but, for simplicity):

```
<div class="container" style="clear:both;">
  <div style="float: left;">content</div>
  <div style="float: left;">content</div>
</div>
```

And did not work. Is it possible to make it work by adding something to the `.container` class??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden; // causes the container to wrap its floated children
}
```

Comment: It only causes scollbars if you use `overflow: auto`. See http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: or you can float the parent container too, with a width is ususally best - and if it's default width is 100% then that saves any hidden content issues or unwanted scrollbars

Comment: Floating the parent container without any width declaration causes it to perfectly shrinkwrap around the dimensions of its child elements - this is another option.

Comment: Interesting, so there doesn't seem to be a need for "clearfix" any more nowadays? I started a question asking to confirm this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix

Answer (score 4):

> **Edit:** Using a clearfix is only necessary in certain cases as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix). `overflow: hidden`  is the superior method.

There is a technique called [clearfix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) that does not require a clearing element, and has been built with a lot of care for cross-browser compatibility. That leads to a lot of browser-specific CSS, but that can be integrated into an existing style sheet.