# Is clearfix deprecated?

Tags: html, css, clearfix

You are aware of the age-old  problem: Containers containing floated elements don't automatically expand their height to enclose their children.

One approach to fix this is the ["clearfix"](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) which adds a number of CSS rules to ensure a container stretches properly.

However, just giving the container `overflow: hidden` seems to work just as well, and with the same amount of browser compatibility.

According to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642565/what-is-the-different-between-clearfix-hack-and-overflowhidden-vs-overflowauto), both methods are compatible across all browsers that are important today.

Does this mean that "clearfix" is deprecated? Is there any advantage left in using it over `overflow: hidden`?

There is a very similar question here: [What is the different between clearfix hack and overflow:hidden vs overflow:auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642565/what-is-the-different-between-clearfix-hack-and-overflowhidden-vs-overflowauto)
 but the question isn't really answered there.

Comment: FWIW, I see both methods as hacks, strictly speaking. I will recommend using `overflow` over clearfix almost all the time though, because it's just much cleaner. Note that at the end of the day, the fact that `overflow: hidden` creates a new BFC allowing a box to contain its floats is still little more than a side effect, and not the original intended purpose of `overflow`. Remember, folks, it's called `overflow`, not `float-contain` or some such.

Comment: These answers may be worth reading if you're interested in the reasoning for such behavior with `overflow`: [Why does overflow: hidden have the unexpected side-effect of growing in height to contain floated elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12783114) and [Why does CSS2.1 define overflow values other than “visible” to establish a new block formatting context?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11854515)

Comment: It seems that `overflow: hidden` is better, but why do the folks over at the HTML5 Boilerplate still use it? `.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can pretty much use `overflow: hidden` all the time.

But, there *are* exceptions. Here's an example of one:

[Overflowing a container div horizontally but not vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616715/overflowing-a-container-div-horizontally-but-not-vertically)

The question there was:

- There's a fixed height on this: http://jsfiddle.net/je8aS/2/
- Without the fixed height: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/je8aS/5/
- *How to clear the floats without using a fixed height?*
- `overflow: hidden` doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/je8aS/6/
- You have to use some other method of clearing floats, such as `clear: both`:
  http://jsfiddle.net/je8aS/3/
- The [clearfix class](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/) also works: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/je8aS/11/

---

Here's a more important example of when you can't use `overflow: hidden`:

http://fordinteractive.com/misc/overflow/

That's not to say that clearfix is the *only* alternative - `display: inline-block` cleanly fixes that example:

http://jsbin.com/ubapog

Comment: The opening statement that `overflow: hidden` can be used all the time is later contradicted by a counter example. Maybe state the caveat and the alternatives in the first sentence?

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in another answer the downside to `hidden` is that it will, surprisingly ermm hide things like dropdown menus. However there is another way to contain with one line, by floating the parent container. This generally works where `overflow: hidden` has a downside, and also floating helps with a lot of legacy IE issues, again especially in lists. If you can use a width then I would use a "float in a float", or `display: inline-block`.

I'm not saying the "clearfix" has no use - but to me it's too widely entrenched into CMS themes (like Wordpress and Drupal) that I think in a lot of cases it's used too much and on divs that don't actually need to be cleared or contained.

I can't actually think of a situation where I can't use either overflow or float, over clearfix, but my brain's in holiday mode - but as it, clearfix, is a copy/paste solution that's sometimes the easiest thing to recommend, however it has to be the one which sets hasLayout for IE, which of course both overflow and float do too now as well.

---

**added**
this has just come up again: and brain not in holiday mode..

I'm really starting to think yes, **clearfix is not necessary** (at least I haven't yet found an example where it is) even @thirtydot's example above can be worked around with `display: inline-block` and still have IE6 support, the container having a fixed width has the IE7 and below hasLayout requirement, and by making it an inline-block for all other browsers it can be centered and the "offset" sticky-out elements will work fine while the container does stretch vertically

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/sJqnA/)

I've also seen reference to a new improved clearfix for those collapsing margins using  `:before` as well as `:after` in the clearfix hack, but unless I'm missing something the   [the demo is flawed](http://www.tjkdesign.com/lab/clearfix/new-clearfix.html)  -  there is uneven whitespace in the `pre` elements and the "clearfixed" boxes do not actually contain any floats, as soon as you do float the elements in them, each method performs the same.

Note margins on `pre` elements don't react the same as others anyway (so try it with padding instead of margin to see the same picture while testing).. and there is also another IE "foible" whereby IE doesn't contain margins properly if they're not explicitly specified and in the demo there is explicit margins on the `h2` but not the `p` so all things being equal a clearfixed element as demo'd by TJK in that page is artificially forcing the containment of the margins on a normal block element, much the same way as 1px top/bottom padding would do because browsers do this differently anyway!

If you do then float the elements inside those containers (the point of clearing anyway) - the margins do then contain as you would probably like them to, as they would if inside a new Block Formatting Context - without any extra `:before` part to the hack, all clearfix variations work equally well!

**[See the demo reloaded](http://jsbin.com/iyefe6)**

So to my mind there is no need for this "clearfix" way anymore, simply find the best way to create that new Block Formatting Context, using haslayout for older IE's.. the properties for both are the same!

as TJK does point out in his article : http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/

> **Better alternatives**
>
> If you can apply a width to the
>   element containing floats, then your
>   best option is to use:
>
> `display: inline-block;` `width: <any
>   explicit value>;`

I think that's fair and even with 100% elements which might need padding, you can do it in conjunction with `box-sizing`

```
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  *width: auto;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`overflow:hidden` is very 'powerful' (I've been using it for several years, and I agree to what David said) but at the same time exposes to a problem. If i.e. inside the container you have some abs elements that you have to drag and drop outside of it, u won't be able to see them outside the container. In this particular case u need to use that 'clearfix' trick ;)

Comment: Ah, fair enough! That makes sense as to why it is still around, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's "deprecated" by [CSS Display L3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/):

> Created the [`flow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-flow) and [`flow-root`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-flow-root) [inner display types](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inner-display-type)
>   to better express flow layout [display types](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#display-type) and to create an
>   explicit switch for making an element a [BFC](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#bfc) root. (This should
>   eliminate the need for hacks like `::after { clear: both; }` and
>   `overflow: hidden` that are intended to accomplish this purpose.)

So now, the proper way is

```css
display: flow-root;
```

Sadly it's a recent addition, so browsers haven't implemented it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've been recommending the `overflow: hidden` method for many years. It is widely supported.

Comment: The "clearfix" solution I link to uses a lot of browser-specific CSS and `:after` to avoid having to use an extra element. What I don't get is why they went through this when there was `overflow: hidden` all along. I suspect it was compatibility issues in *really* early browsers like IE5 or something. Anyway, if `hidden` works everywhere, there is no reason for using anything else any more. Thanks

Comment: OK, I'm clearly tired and making too many assumptions. I love release Wednesday. Edited the answer so it doesn't mention irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered to my pleasant surprise that `overflow:hidden` works perfectly nowadays. I had been using the clearfix method up until around 6 months ago and it is quite bloated in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Make sure you have the correct DOCTYPE set if you're just testing. Caught me out a few times and I always forget!

In IE9 for instance the following just won't work without `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

#bottom_panel {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: orange;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#bottom_panel .col1 {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100px
}

#bottom_panel .col2 {
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 70px
}

#bottom_panel .col3 {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    width: 150px
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

</style>

<div id="bottom_panel">

    <div class="col1">this is col 1</div>
    <div class="col2">this is col 2. It's taller than the other columns because it's got more text in ot</div>
    <div class="col3">this is col 3</div>

</div>

<div>
This should not be floating around! Should be underneath the columns!
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that clearfixing is deprecated. However, I would say that most versions of the clearfix currently being used are outdated.

[According to the experts](http://cssmojo.com/latest_new_clearfix_so_far/), this is the version your should use today:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```