# Designing wordpress theme problem

Tags: wordpress, floating

I'm designing a wordpress theme from scratch.
I used boxes for posts - two posts per row.
The CSS code is:

```
#box  {
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:10px;
width:240px;
}
.left {
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
}
```

and there's wrapper to wrap all boxes in page:

```
#wrapper{
     width:980px;
     background-color:#fff;
```

}

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="box" class="left">
...WP tags and...
</div>
</div>
```

so all boxes are in the wrapper. Now the problem is wrapper doesn't show up - no white background on the page, but as soon as i remove float property wrapper come into the play.
How can I fix that!?

Comment: Inspect the document with a document inspector like Chrome's "right-click > inspect element", or Firebug. It will show you where the element goes to.

Comment: Firebug, that's what I'm living with !

Comment: what are the element's x and y coordinates? Maybe it is hidden behind some other element?

Comment: What elements exactly do u mean?

Comment: I realize now I totally misread your question. I'm sorry. Disregard my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the wrapper element `overflow: hidden`.

```
#wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:980px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

It is the [accepted method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix) of making this work across all browsers. It works better and with less hassle than the clearfix workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The boxes are "floating" on top of the wrapper. Simply add clear:both; to #wrapper.
Oh and by the way, you don't need to create 3 element for your margin, you can write it on one line, like that margin:0 10px 10px 0; (top, right, bottom, left)
Also a little trick you should use when debugging css, add border:solid 1px red; so you can see what you are doing.

Comment: clearing both didn't work. Margins r in one line firebug shows them separately. i already tested border with firebug, wrapper is before boxes, on top, a very narrow horizontal line

Answer (score 0):

You will need a clearfix
http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html