# .clearfix still needed?

Tags: html, css

One last question. The code I inherited has the following:

```
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

Seems like a lot of hacks. Is this still needed for the modern browsers IE7 and upwards?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use all that for modern browsers.

Simply using `overflow: hidden` works and is sufficient in 99% of cases.

See this relevant question that discusses this in depth:

- [Is clearfix deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix)

Comment: Where do I put the overflow: hidden? I am used to adding the class="clearfix" to many of my <div>  Can I put this in a css for something like body { } ?

Comment: I tend to just add `overflow: hidden` to each element that requires it. So if you had a div containing floats: `<div id="container">`, in your CSS you would write `#container { overflow: hidden }`. **Do not** put `overflow: hidden` on `body`: this will prevent your page from being able to scroll.

Comment: Thank you. I added it to the CSS definition of a div that had an ID. But I have more divs inside that div. Will it be inherited by divs within divs?

Comment: No, the [`overflow` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow) is not *inheritable*. However, the clearfix class *also* isn't inheritable - as you said, you're used to adding the `clearfix` class to many `div`s. You only need to add float clearance to `div`s that contain elements that are `float`ed. You should not need to (float clear) add `overflow: hidden` to many elements.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple cross-browser method that has always worked for me is placing this below any floated content:

```
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Or you can use `class="clear"` if you want to be neater.

Having the space there isn't always necessary but there are cases when it is.

Answer (score -1):

I still use it simply because I'd rather have `class="clear"` vs `overflow: auto` or `hidden` on all my elements.