# floats and blocking containers

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/2yr2A/19/

How do you make containers with floating elements block around the floating elements

Here is the HTML.

```
<div>
    <label> foo </label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label> foo </label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

And CSS

```
input {
    height: 50px;
    float: right;    
    clear: right;
}
```

And it displays like so :

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
| foo                                 -----------------|
|-------------------------------------|---------------||
| foo                                 |               |
|-------------------------------------|---------------|
                                      |---------------|
                                      |---------------|
                                      |               |
                                      |               |
                                      |               |
                                      |---------------|
```

I would like it to display like :

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
| foo                                 -----------------|
|                                     |               ||
|                                     |               ||
|                                     |               ||
|                                     |---------------||
|------------------------------------------------------|
| foo                                 |---------------||
|                                     |               ||
|                                     |               ||
|                                     |               ||
|                                     |---------------||
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

What is the correct CSS trickery to fix this?

Comment: Just `overflow: hidden`: http://jsfiddle.net/2yr2A/20/ + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix works in "every browser".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try styling your div's with overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You need the [clearfix trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)! Basically, use CSS pseudoselectors to stick an empty block-level element after the wrapping div, forcing it to expand past the floated items. See http://jsfiddle.net/82RWe/

Comment: Raynos, if you follow the tutorial Chowlett pointed to it will work in IE... note the * hacks.

Comment: @Micheal Do I have to resort to broken CSS parser hacks?

Comment: @Raynos: No. See my comment on your question. I would've posted it as an answer, but it's already there. Though I didn't upvote it for lack of effort.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .InnerDiv {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .InnerDiv input {
    height: 20px;
    width:100px;
    float:right;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="InnerDiv">
        <span> foo </span>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="InnerDiv">
        <span> foo </span>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will solve the problem for static content with height<=50px only.

Comment: I don't want to use absolute width/heights.