# Wrapping a containing div with another div

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to summarize my situation, but here's the simplified code showing the problem (index.html) :

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper" class="divide">
          <div id="top" class="divide">
                ....(all of its contents)....
          </div>
          <div id="content" class="divide">
              <div id="left">
                  ....(all the contents)....
               </div>
               <div id="right">
                  ....(all the contents)....
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div id="footer">
       </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

(style.css)

```
.divide{
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   width:960px;
 }

 body {
   background-color: #666600;
 }
 #left {
     ......
     ......
     float: left;
 }

  #right {
     ......
     ......
     float: left;
 }

 #wrapper{
    background-color:#ffffff;
  }
```

So here I want the "wrapper" div background to be white in color, and the body background surrounding it to have another color (in here I put the brownish color). This works for the "top" div, but not the "content" div (thus, all of its children). The "content" div has the same background color as body, which doesn't make sense to me because the "wrapper" div does contain "content" div.

In other word, the "wrapper" div seems doesn't reach the "content" div and all of its children. Is there any workaround for this problem? Inform me if you all need additional information. Thanks for any help!

NOTE: As our helpful people pointed out, the floating properties in the div element does cause the above problem. I did not realize that. That's why I didn't put the floating properties in the first place. So I just edited the above code so that we know what's really causing it. Peace!

Comment: does your content div have floated elements only?

Comment: not sure. i'll need to check back to my whole code.

Comment: there was some floating properties in the code. i thought it wasn't really a problem until you guys pointed it out. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any floated elements, such as `#left` and `#right`?

If so, you need to [clear your floats](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

One way to do that is to add `overflow: hidden` to `#wrapper`.

You should also fix a small mistake in your HTML: `</left>` to `</div>`.

Comment: it wasnt me. i havent checked your solution yet

Comment: Same..dunno why we got downvoted. +1 to counter :D you had my answer neway, but beat me by a sec

Comment: @AlienWebguy: I suspect that he's reduced his CSS down to what he *thinks* is the relevant part, like he's done with his HTML. Look at the names of the `div`s: `left` and `right`. I might be wrong - if I am, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: there was some floating properties in the code. i thought it wasn't really a problem until you guys pointed it out. thanks!

Comment: @thirtydot hahah i just noticed you answered my very same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956707/problem-with-div-bg-color-styl-in-ff-chrome good stuff :p

Comment: @Shredder: I answer [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/topusers) of CSS questions :)

Answer (score 3):

If you float your content divs, you might be having a problem with not clearing the floats. Try adding `overflow:auto` to your wrapper div

Comment: i did not do it, that's for sure

Comment: I did. Do you see the word `float` in the CSS?

Comment: @AlienWebguy Perhaps the OP left it out. Its pretty much a given when you're doing div columns... the given code wouldn't allow him to make left/right div columns, so you can assume he left it out.

Comment: Yep he admitted to being a moron. Edit your answer and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Wtf do you want me to edit. This is probably the answer to his problem

Comment: Just change one letter, I don't care if you do or not but if you want me to remove the downvote, you have to edit your answer cuz it's locked.

Comment: @vandershraaf thx :D I had the exact same problem and turned to SO haha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956707/problem-with-div-bg-color-styl-in-ff-chrome. +1->Question

Comment: @vandershraaf and what do you know, thirtydot answered it hahah!

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into JSFiddle and got this: http://jsfiddle.net/XPLWR/, it looks fine to me.

Comment: so there should be any other thing causes this?

Comment: @vandershraaf Most likely a `float` on one of the `div`s inside the wrapper. If an element is floated it's removed from the regular flow and thus won't cause the wrapper to extend further. One solution would be to add `clear:both;` to your `content` and `header` IDs.

Comment: @ Andrew Peacock, you're totally right. i'm still a newbie in this css stuff, so thanks for pointing it out.