# How to set a:link height/width with css?

Tags: html, css

I just can't set the height and width of `a` elements of my navigation.

```
#header div#snav div a{
    width:150px;
    height:77px;
}

#header div#snav div a:link{
    width:150px;
    height:77px;
}


#header div#snav div a:hover{
    height:77px;
    background:#eff1de;
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

add display: block;

a-tag is an inline element so your height and width are ignored.

```
#header div#snav div a{
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:77px;
}
```

Comment: Block has the side effect that it will create a new line after the element.

Answer (score 32):

Anchors will need to be a different display type than their default to take a height.
`display:inline-block;` or `display:block;`.

Also check on `line-height` which might be interesting with this.

Comment: line-height is also a great solution. But when the text in the link will go over 2 lines the whitespace between those 2 line is huge.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is probably that  `a` elements are `display: inline` by nature. You can't set the width and height of inline elements.

You would have to set `display: block` on the `a`, but that will bring other problems because the links start behaving like block elements. The most common cure to that is giving them `float: left` so they line up  side by side anyway.

Comment: Floating them will probably prevent their parent element from expanding around them.

Comment: @Cobra yup, but that is easily fixed. [In 2011, is there any need for clearfix?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5565668)

Comment: So we need to fix the fix here? That doesnt sound very well.

Answer (score 5):

From the [definition of height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> Applies to:   all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table columns, and column groups

An `a` element is, by default an inline element (and it is non-replaced).

You need to change the display (directly with the display property or indirectly, e.g. with float).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to RandomUs 1r for this observation:

> changing it to display:inline-block; solves that issue. –  RandomUs1r May 14 '13 at 21:59

I tried it myself for a top navigation menu bar, as follows:

First style the "li" element as follows:

> display: inline-block;
>   width: 7em;
>   text-align: center;

Then style the "a"> element as follows:

> width: 100%;

Now the navigation links are all equal width with text centered in each link.