# Getting my DIVs to line up seems hard

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple code:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>Topic</div>
    <div>Sub Topic</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>test 1</div>
    <div>Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want to get "test 1" to appear right of Topic. Now it appear below. Is there a way to solve with CSS?

Comment: But you're not using any CSS. Right now you're just using the default styles of the web browser. In other words, not only *can* you solve it with CSS, but you *must* use CSS if you are going to try using a generic tag such as `<div>`. As it stands right now, this is woefully incomplete code.

Comment: @stargazer i think *woefully incomplete* is an exaggeration. the answers are shorter than your comment

Comment: @qntmfred, it is woefully incomplete in a *conceptual* fashion. Writing code using nothing but `<div>`'s and expecting it to do anything useful shows a very incomplete knowledge of the general framework of the web.

Comment: You should totally be using a `dl` ([definition list](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/)) here. Answer incoming.

Comment: @stargazer it was complete enough for everybody who answered to understand what she wanted. when somebody asks a question about CSS, it isn't necessary to point out that their knowledge of CSS is incomplete.

Comment: @qntmfred, if someone were trying to hack the linux kernel without learning C, I'd tell them to learn C and come back. Christina is trying to do web programming without even knowing what CSS is meant for. Go learn CSS and come back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left;width:200px;">
    <div>Topic</div>
    <div>Sub Topic</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;width:200px;">
    <div>test 1</div>
    <div>Test 2</div>
  </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i added an extra div to clear the floats which can solve some common cross browser issues.

Comment: You need to fix `float:left:width:200px;` into `float:left semicolon_goes_here width:200px;`. It's amazing how many people upvote an answer with glaring mistakes :)

Comment: @qntmfred: I'd have fixed it myself, *after a while*. I'd prefer to let @Treemonkey fix it for himself, that way he's less likely to make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: Not to take away from this right answer, but it muddies up the markup with the need for adding an additional div each time you want to clear the floats. My solution is the preferred way to clear floats per the best practices found at [Html5Boilerplate](http://www.html5boilerplate.com)

Comment: @Scott: You can simply use `overflow: hidden` 99% of the time, as in my answer. It's a whole lot shorter to include in an Stack Overflow answer than `clearfix` :)

Comment: @thirtydot - I tend to stick with best practices from the guru that is Paul Irish at Html5Boilerplate. I understand that overflow: hidden works in most cases, but I like how the .clearfix in my solution addresses the specific issues and makes certain that all basis are covered.

Comment: @Scott: I'm not arguing with that, but here's some background info: you might like to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix/5566093 - I had to rack my brains to think of an example where `overflow: hidden` *didn't work*. @clairesuzy also points out another instance where `overflow: hidden` won't do it (dropdown menus). I personally dislike `clearfix` because you have to add an extra class in your HTML for something that should be handled purely in CSS. I also (again) dislike using it in Stack Overflow answers because it's long.

Comment: @thirtydot - That's your prerogative and you are entitled to that.  I understand what you are saying, I am simply saying that this "accepted answer" is not really a complete solution and is worse in terms of muddying up the markup.  As far as `overflow: hidden` vs `.clearfix`, I'll stick with my `.clearfix` which is a very elegant solution compared to the other `.clearfix` solutions.  I just don't like solutions that don't cover all basis, even if it is only 1% =D.

Comment: @Scott: I don't like the answers to this question (including yours) that [other than my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112783/getting-my-divs-to-line-up-seems-hard/6112966#6112966) because they are "div soup". The `dl` element is a far better choice. I think we can both agree the accepted answer is not the best answer, but that's because the OP is not very experienced.

Comment: @thirtydot - I agree with you on the Html5 `dl` element.  That does seem how the OP intends to use the data.  However, I disagree that my answer is div soup. It does not add anything extra to the markup.  It uses a class, just as yours does.  To me, at this point, it's purely semantics.

Answer (score 5):

As in my comment, I'm using a `dl` element here.

The HTML is far more semantic, and much lighter:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/46WRw/

```
<dl class="topics">
    <dt>Topic</dt>
    <dd>test 1</dd>

    <dt>Sub Topic</dt>
    <dd>Test 2</dd>
</dl>

.topics {
    overflow: hidden; /* clear floated child elements */
    background: #ccc;
    width: 200px
}
.topics dt, .topics dd {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 50%
}
.topics dt {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the others, I would use `float: left`, but you need to clear the parent div too like in this ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/juh38/)***.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <div>Topic</div>
    <div>Sub Topic</div>
  </div>
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <div>test 1</div>
    <div>Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

Hello
```

**CSS:**

```
div { 

    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border: dotted 1px black; 

}

.floatLeft { float: left; }

/* The Magnificent Clearfix: 
   Updated to prevent margin-collapsing on child elements. 
   j.mp/bestclearfix */

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { 

    content: "\0020"; 
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 

}

.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

/* Fix clearfix: 
   blueprintcss.lighthouseapp.com/projects/15318/tickets/5-extra-margin-padding-bottom-of-page */

.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use divs. (Though you can use `float:right` and `float:left` for aligning divs on the same row)
Use tables:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Topic</td>
<td>Test 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sub Topic</td>
<td>Test 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of tables, but this does solve the question.

Comment: Don't use tables for anything that is not considered tabular data.

Comment: @tjameson @Loktar yeah, i wouldn't always recommend it but it seemed OP had some tabular data here.

Comment: also if you wanted to use a table then should really use the correct markup for the titles :P

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <div>Topic</div>
    <div>Sub Topic</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
    <div>test 1</div>
    <div>Test 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this is tabulated data though, you can can use tables for it.  And that is a perfectly valid thing to do.

Comment: This answer doesn't work if there is a lot of words instead of just "test 1" or "test 2" :-(

Comment: @Christina not sure what the other words are - check this example out http://jsfiddle.net/4PkDA/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it should be pretty easy using selectors.

```
div div div{
     display: inline;
}
```

This will only select the `div`s that are children of two `div`s.

Comment: `div div div { display:inline }` should actually do the same. And `div > div > div { display:inline }` doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the IE issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a CSS framework to do this. I personally like Blueprint the best. Even when you get to an advanced level in page layout with CSS, a framework is still useful in achieving trivial effects like the one you've described very quickly.

Checkout:

http://www.blueprintcss.org/

http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/

http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/sample.html

For more information and sample code.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
div { overflow:hidden; width:100% }
div div { width:auto; float:left }
div div div { float:none }
```

No clearing `div` needed.