# How to not use <div class="clear"> in markup

Tags: css, xhtml

All the time my code is riddled with `<div>`'s that are used to clear/expand a div to look correct. Whenever it doesn't look correct, I add a `<div style="clear:both;">` and it fixes the problem in IE7.

How do I avoid doing this? I mess with the `overflow:auto`, `overflow:hidden` and I get nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some code for the uninitiated to demo this issue?

Comment: clear: both is often required to push content below a floated element. There is (usually) nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In 2011, is there any need for clearfix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/in-2011-is-there-any-need-for-clearfix) and [Which method of 'clearfix' is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: Also useful: [Which method of clearfix is best](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: @George that is a great link, thanks.

Answer (score 35):

One common method is the `clearfix` class.  Instead of needing extraneous `<div style="clear:both;">` elements (as you have been doing) after the floating element, you simply add this class to the floating element *itself* and the layout is automatically cleared after it.<sup>**1**</sup>

My favorite one is from http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack.  It supports modern browsers as well as IE6 and IE7.

```
/* new clearfix */
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Example (old/bad):

```
<div class="floatingrightmenu">This floats right</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<p>This text is cleared below it.</p>
```

Example (new with `clearfix`):

```
<div class="floatingrightmenu clearfix">This floats right</div>
<p>This text is cleared below it.</p>
```

---

<sup>**1:** Note: the automatic clearing means that it works best with single floated elements.  If you wish to have multiple elements floated next to each other, put them all into a single container which is also floated and apply `clearfix` to that container.</sup>

Comment: @Kristian - I did not interpret the question that way.  I interpreted it to say that he wishes to avoid "code is riddled with `<div>`'s", in other words, having to place `<div style="clear:both;">` *after* floated elements.  This is the exact fix for that.

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen No, he wants to avoid empty div's with `clear: both`. This clearfix class should be added to the container which holds the floating elements. If done, he get rid of the empty div's.

Comment: @Renesis, @DanielB If that's the case, I believe (for the most part) there still are ways to avoid using either. Still waiting for a demo issue, though.

Comment: This could, in same cases, be exactly what you need. Although this option gives less flexibility when creating responsive websites. clear:both; is ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

if you pop overflow:hidden; on the container of the floating elements that should work! dunno how cross browser it is however.

Answer (score 1):

In [**Cascade Framework**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/) I apply the micro-clearfix by default on block level elements. This allows you to avoid the use of stuff like `<div style="clear:both;">` or `<div class="clearfix">` with but very minimal side-effects. And if you really want traditional behavior for block level elements, absolute positioning should do the trick. Check out [**Cascade Framework**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/) for yourself to get an idea of how practical it really is.

Comment: When I navigate to Cascade Framework, I see only a couple of paragraphs. There is no code at all.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray : Thanks for pointing this out. I no longer own the domain name cascade-framework.com and forgot to update these links to point to the github demo for this project instead. I just updated my answer with the correct URL!