# What are the downsides to using "clear:both" to clear floating divs?

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

It seems that the community here agrees that the old "clearfix" hack has now been [depreciated and superseded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/is-clearfix-deprecated) by `overflow:hidden`. Unfortunately there are situations where even using this method causes problems. (For example: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/je8aS/6/) would look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D9U9N/) if it worked correctly.)

The main problem with using the old fashioned `<div class="clear">` seems to be that it creates a `div` element for sole purpose of altering the presentation -- which seems to be muddying the ideal of pure semantic markup with presentation.

Other than that, though, it appears to work well with all browsers and in all situations (which cannot be said for "clearfix" or `overflow:hidden`).

Are there any other drawbacks to using `clear:both`? Is it really that bad to use? Or is it just personal preference?

Comment: `overflow:hidden` (or `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll`) was _supposed_ to be _the_ way to wrap one's contents.

Comment: Personally, I'm against `overflow:hidden;`, when you use it, you'll have to say byebye to `absolute` divs inside the div; specially notifications, message boxes, hints, stuff like that, you're forced to put them all inside.

Comment: I would look more closely before following the community in using `overflow: hidden`. It is fine in some situations and problematic in others. See @clairesuzy's answer to the question you referenced (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5566031/101869) and then also have a look at the conversation at "Which method of 'clearfix' is best?" (http://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/101869). In my answer I outline why I think `display: inline-block` is the most robust solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9932508/101869).

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. Not as nice as a pure CSS method, no, but there are times when overflow:hidden / auto just won't work well (for example, when you want an absolutely positioned element to 'pop' out of its container).

Yes, it adds a maintainability cost, and yes, it's theoretically suboptimal for SEO, but it's hardly a cardinal sin.

Answer (score 1):

### There are side effects

`clear: both` has a side effect that if there are any other floats present in the same block formatting context, the `clear: both` element will be forced below them. Sometimes this is what you want. Sometimes it isn't. This [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eladob/4/edit) demonstrates a case where it will eat your lunch:

[image: Example of when <code>clear: both</code> causes problems.]

The trick is in controlling which floats a cleared element should interact with. You do this with block formatting contexts, an insulated rectangle inside of which all floats and cleared elements interact. Floats and cleared elements outside of a block formatting context cannot interact with floats or cleared elements inside.

This is one important drawback to keep in mind when using `clear: both`. Is it really that bad to use? No. You just have to be aware of how floats and clears interact and how to prevent them from doing so when you need to. In many situations these issues don't come up, so choosing a method for clearing floats can be a matter of personal preference. But some situations demand a deeper consideration of how floating and clearing works. Every clearing method has side effects, so you have to pick the right one for your situation. There are detailed answers at [Which method of 'clearfix' is best?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/101869)

Comment: When building complex apps, you're often nesting layouts inside of other layouts. For this case, assume there are other floats inside of the main grey area that you are trying to clear. What will end up happening is that the first `clear:both` and everything that follows will be pushed down below the sidebar.

Comment: Have another look, @DjangoReinhardt. Let me know if this makes the situation I'm describing more clear.

Comment: Thanks, I took another look. If you clear all your floats, there's no issue: http://jsbin.com/eladob/6/

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt, the reason that works is you floated the main content section, which makes it a new block formatting context, not because you cleared all of the floats. The problem with this approach is that you can't have the main section fill the remaining horizontal space (you set a fixed width). Without the fixed width your layout breaks. You may not prefer this style, but this demonstrates why `clear: both` can have unintended side effects.

Comment: Cool, gotcha. I can't imagine many sites filling the whole width of the screen with content, and even less that use floats in the same you've suggested, but I'm sure there's some that legitimately do that! Thanks!

Comment: Are these the only side-effects you know of? And are they unique to clear:both (i.e. would using overflow:hidden or "clearfix" work ok in this situation?).

Comment: Every solution has side effects. The trick is choosing the right ones for your situation. `overflow: hidden` has the side effect of clipping content that falls outside the bounds of the element. Traditional clearfix solutions are very similar to `clear: both` and will have the same side effects. I outlined that I think is the most robust method for insulating and containing floats in my answer to "Which method of 'clearfix' is best?" http://stackoverflow.com/a/9932508/101869

Comment: ? `"Clearfix"` has its own set of issues that `clear: both` doesn't have. It would be great if you could answer the questions I asked you. Thanks!

Comment: If you want detailed answers to follow-up questions, I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: I asked two questions: They're both "yes" or "no". And I'm asking because they result in whether I accept your answer or not (more the second one than the first).

Answer (score 0):

`clear:both` simply means that there are no floats allowed to the left or right. An alternate method does exist, but it isn't safe for older browsers.

```
.element:after { content:""; clear:both; }
```

I'm pretty sure clear: is standard, floats are just tricky if you do not fully understand them (it took me a while).

The reason the white space exists is that floated elements do not actually 'exist', in the sense that they give no definitive dimensions for the container to wrap around. You can use `clear:left` `clear:right` or `clear:both` on an item after the float and it will create a hard line, the same as using the `<div class="clear"></div>` method.

Personally, I use the tried-and-true hack and add pseudo elements for when it's (hopefully) supported all around.

Comment: Worth pointing out that most browsers ignore dynamic content when they print - so clearfix won't work if you need a paper output.