# How to position an element to the right side?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a css element to the right side of the header but not sure exactly how to do it. I tried using:

```
 position: Absolute; top: 20px; right 0px;
```

That would work but if you adjust the browser the text moves with it.

I created a JFiddle that you can find here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rKWXQ/

This way you can see what I am trying to do. I have a text inside a wrapped div element that says Call Now (555) 555-5555.

Here is the header element and inside of that I have a right_header element.

```
    <div id="header">
        <span class="right_header">Call Now (555) 555-5555</span>
    </div>
```

Here is my Header CSS:

```
   /* Header */
   #header {margin: auto; width: 1007px; height: 123px; background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 20px; background-color: #37352b; border: 1px solid #862209;}
  .right_header{color: #fff; position: absolute; top: 70px; right: 0px}
```

Can someone please tell me the proper way to accomplish this please?

Note the left side will have a logo there that will not load in JFiddle!

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can easily just `float` it to the right, no need for `relative` or `absolute` positioning.

```
.right_header {
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
}
```

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rKWXQ/1/) - might need to add some `padding`/`margins` - [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/LG2vR/).

Comment: That did it!!! Ugg why didn't I think of that hahaha I'm sorry I should have got it! Now I'm disappointed been trying to learn this stuff and I missed it. Thank you!

Comment: Beat me to it, +1 :P Further reading: This will come useful when floating things inside non-floated containers: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

Comment: @francisco.preller Yea, that might be helpful. Alternatively, applying `overflow:hidden` to the parent works essentially the same as a clearfix - forcing it to contain it's children.

Comment: Didn't know about overflow:hidden, nice thanks. Seems there are some caveats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/is-clearfix-deprecated

Comment: @francisco.preller that link was helpful! Thank you!!

Answer (score 19):

Two more ways to do it:

1. Using margins on the element you want to position to the right of its parent.

```
.element {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

2. Using flexbox on the parent element:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

Comment: Great! You don't need to cancel the float further ahead.

Answer (score 8):

As JoshC mentioned, using `float` is one option. I think your situation suggests another solution, though.

You need to set `position: relative` on your `#header` element in order for the `position: absolute` on your `#right_header` to take effect. once you set that, you are free to position `#right_header` however you want relative to `#header`

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful! But float can do it to. Is there any difference between using a float or position? Or I should say is it better to use position vs float?

Comment: @FrankG. I usually avoid absolute positioning for the exact reason you were mentioning, however floats have their downfalls too. It's worth mentioning that absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this way also if you want to do with position, Try this please

```
 #header {margin: auto; position:relative; width: 1007px; height: 123px; background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 20px; background-color: #37352b; border: 1px solid #862209;}


.right_header{color: #fff; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px}
```

Comment: @Frank G. Check this  CSS Also.

Answer (score 1):

The answer using floats from JoshC will work fine, however, I think there is a reason this is not working.

The reason your code does not work, is that the absolute position is relative to the  which has dimensions of 0x0.

The '' should be absolutely position in order for this code to work.

```
#header {margin: auto; width: 1007px; height: 123px; background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 20px; background-color: #37352b; border: 1px solid #862209;}
```

change it to...

```
#header {margin: auto; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top 0px; height: 123px; background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat 20px; background-color: #37352b; border: 1px solid #862209;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div><button>Continue</button></div>`
to make button on the right of div

```
<style>
button {
 display:block;
 margin-left:auto;
}
</style>
```