# Can I use flexbox to give an element layout, and therefore deprecate clearfix?

Tags: css, flexbox, clearfix

Similar, but not the same as [Is clearfix deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/is-clearfix-deprecated).

I have a web app targeted at modern browsers. Flexbox is used everywhere for vertical centering. The only real CSS/SASS hack is clearfix:

```
@mixin clearfix {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

**Is there any aspect of flexbox I can use to ensure an element contains its children, so I can stop using clearfix hacks?**

I understand this is called 'hasLayout' by browser rendering engines.

Comment: You don't need the clearfix if you don't use `float`s.

Comment: Please could you provide an example showing how you are currently using clearfix in a flexbox layout?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes the point is that I'm *not* currently using flexbox, which is why I'm using clearfix.

Comment: @pawel Do you want to add that as an answer? Testing it, it seems like: the only reason to use clearfix is for floats, flexbox gives me items beside each other without floats, and the `display: flex` item containing the items will expand to fill the contents,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `flex`ed item will scale with the size of its children assuming you don't set a specific `height`, so you won't need to rely on `float`, or by extension clearfix. I've got a [pen](http://codepen.io/KBD/pen/RPdxNr) where I'm playing with `flex` at the moment.

The rules I'm using are:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}
.child {
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}
```

And then for each child, I'm specifying a width that I want it to fill.

For these rules, `display:flex` tells the parent to display as a flexbox. `flex-flow` is a short-hand for `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` - in this case I'm telling the parent to have its children sit in a row, and when they reach the end of the available width, wrap down to the next line. `justify-content: space-between` helps with horizontal spacing between the children, removing the need to cancel a `margin` at the end of the row. `align-content: space-between` helps add some vertical spacing. I've found that I do have to add `margin-bottom` onto the children just to create a little white space.

A quick caveat, though, is that if you do still need to use `float`s for whatever reason, it would be good to clear them still.