# CSS border is not wrapping whole div content

Tags: html, css

This is my html code which has "box" as main div and then three divs inside it
which are positioned left,middle and right respectively.

```
<div id="box">
 <div class="left">Left</div>     
 <div class="middle">Middle</div>
 <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

And this is my css code

```
#box {
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    border:5px solid green;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}
.middle {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
```

This is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/hep9oLzn/
The border is not wrapping the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of the floated  children elements.

[All about floats - CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

You need a `clearfix`.

[What is clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

As an example here's a micro `clearfix`. [Micro Clearfix Hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

```css
#box {
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    border:5px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}
.middle {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="cf">
    <div class="left">Left</div>     
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And assigning overflow:hidden; property to main div is also working ,how this works ?  can you please explain which one is better, using clearfix or assigning this property ?

Comment: @BrainyPrb depends on your specific case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565668/is-clearfix-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

just add float:left to #box,

```css
#box {
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    border:5px solid green;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add position: absolute; to #box.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hep9oLzn/3/)

```
 #box {
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    border:5px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add display: table; to #box

```
#box {
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    border:5px solid green;
    display: table;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bw0vhske/1/

Some info about display table:
http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hep9oLzn/5/)

HTML Code

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="left">Left</div>     
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
#box {
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    border:5px solid green;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}
.middle {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div#box contains only floated elements, which are removed from the normal float. As a result, your div#box has not height. There are many ways you can use to solve your problem.

One is to set an explicit height to your div.
For example:

```
#box {
    width:90%;
    height:600px;
    border:5px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can use the "clearfix" solution that bootstrap an other ui frameworks use.
For example, add this to use css:

```
#box::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

You can remove the float attribute from your inside divs and make them inline-block. For example:

```
#box > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

You can place a hidden object after your floated elements and use clear: both on it, like:

```
<div id="box" class="cf">
    <div class="left">Left</div>     
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="fix"></div>
</div>

.fix {
      clear: both;
      visibility: hidden;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: The clearfix solution also works with the `outline` CSS property (which are similar to borders in that they wrap around a `div` / element)

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both; }
```